# Unity3D С# Обработка столкновения и дальнейшего расталкивания между двумя объектами

Tags: c#, unity3d

Пробую написать скрипт.
Цель если кратко. 
Есть один или более ботов и игрок. Нужно настроить следование ботов к игроку и друг к другу. В случае когда они соприкоснутся должно произойти событие отталкивающие соприкоснувшихся в противоположные стороны.

**Код на боте.** Бот определяет по тегу где игрок(в идеале далее он должен искать просто близлежащую цель), поворачивается и идет к ней. Срабатывает кализия и цель как бы улетает(отталкивается) от него.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Transform triggerPosition;
    public float enemySpeed = 10.0f;
    public float rotationSpeed = 10.0f;
    public float walkingDistance = 10.0f;
    public float smoothTime = 10.0f;
    private Vector3 smoothVelocity = Vector3.zero;
    public float forceAmount = 10.0f;
    private Rigidbody rb;
    void Start()
    {
        triggerPosition = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player").transform;
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        LookToTrigger();
        EnemyMove();
        Debug.Log("Player Position" + triggerPosition);
    }

    void LookToTrigger()
    {
        Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(triggerPosition.position - transform.position);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    void EnemyMove()
    {
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, triggerPosition.position);
        if (distance < walkingDistance)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, triggerPosition.position, ref smoothVelocity, smoothTime);
        }
    }

    public void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
    {
        pushTo(other);
        other = null;
    }

    void pushTo(Collision c)
    {
        var force = transform.position - c.transform.position;
        if (c.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            force.Normalize();
            rb.AddForce(force * forceAmount);
        }

    }
}
```

**Код на игроке.**
Игрок следует за курсором мыши(находясь постоянно в движение) и в случае столкновения отбрасывает врага(в идеале должен и сам отлетать но это потом)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 6f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        LookOnCursor();
    }

    void LookOnCursor()
    {
        Plane playerPlane = new Plane(Vector3.up, transform.position);
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        float hitdist = 0;
        if (playerPlane.Raycast(ray, out hitdist))
        {
            Vector3 targetPoint = ray.GetPoint(hitdist);
            Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetPoint - transform.position);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

**Из того что есть на сцене.** Пол это круг с Mesh collider. бот и игрок это объекты с capsule collider и rigidbody(вкл гравитация и ограничение ротации по x/z и позиции по y)

**А теперь сама(и) проблема(ы).**
1.OnCollisionEnter срабатывает только один раз(после этого Push не работает)
2.Отталкивает тоже в 50%. Враг или улетает в даль(как? почему) или все же отлетает.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно проблема в том что вы пытаетесь толкнуть бота вовсе не в противоположном направлении, я прямо в точку коллизии. Попробуйте rb.AddForce(-force*forceAmount);

Comment: Все еще не работает.

Comment: возможно стоит убрать строку other = null. Судя по названию, функция OnCollisionEnter  реагирует только на вхождение в коллизию, а вы сразу удаляете ссылку на коллизию. (но это не точно)

Comment: Да я ее после добавил. Оно и до этого плохо работало